# any way to construct efficient features matrix in pandas for binary classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have merged dataframe which is about crime frequency and house sale distribution in Chicago. I want to build an efficient feature matrix for this data. However, I a bit confused about how to construct feature matrix from this dataset, because I want to use binary classification such as `logistic regression`, `SVM` for my data, but I don't know which way I should construct feature matrix. anyone give me possible takeaway to do this? Thanks

**reproducible data**:

```
test_df= pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'], 
                       'Theft': [100,200,300,230, 20,34,56, 65, 43,56,79,109],
                       'Robbery': [100,200,300,230, 20,34,56, 65, 43,56,79,109],
                       'Assult': [102,230,320,235, 201,343,90, 106, 143,156,179,102],
                     'Area': ['Chicago, IL metro area', 'Chicago, IL metro area', 'Chicago, IL metro area', 'Chicago, IL metro area', 'Chicago, IL', 'Chicago, IL', 'Chicago, IL', 'Chicago, IL', 'Chicago, IL - Albany Park', 'Chicago, IL - Albany Park', 'Chicago, IL - Albany Park', 'Chicago, IL - Albany Park'],
                     'yearly_sale_percentage': ['5%', '10%', '7%','21%', '15%', '12%', '2%','21%', '10%', '11%', '12%','6%'],
                     'price_status':[0, 1, 0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]})
```

**here is what I did**:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X= test_df.drop('price_status', axis=1)
X= vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
y= vectorizer.fit_transform(test_df['price_status'])

clf =  sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel=kernel)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

but I didn't get correct feature selection because my data was spanned by year. How can I manipulate above dataframe and build up an efficient feature matrix for a binary classification problem? any efficient solution? Thanks

**goal**:

I want to train SVM classifier different type of crime over price_status. any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for TF-IDF here.

You have to predict `price_status`, so this will be your target column and all other columns will be in your feature matrix. Before directly feeding other columns to an svm we have to process the columns. (All must be converted to numbers). The column `Area` is a categorical variable (it looks like that). We can label encode or one hot encode the `Area` column. The column `yearly_sale_percentange` contains the percentage sign(%). Removing the percentage sign will do our work.

```
# label encoding the area column, you can do one hot encoding also.
test_df['Area']=pd.factorize(test_df['Area'])[0]

# removing the percentage sign
test_df['yearly_sale_percentage']=test_df['yearly_sale_percentage'].apply(lambda x:float(x[:-1]))
```

After this, we can create the feature matrix and then feed it to svm.

```
X=train.iloc[:,:-1].values   # all columns expect the last column(price status)
y=train['price_status'].values

clf=sklearn.svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X,y)

# you can also check the accuracy score as shown below.
print(clf.score(X,y))
```